# Pass information between requests webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Is it possible to pass information between requests with `webapp2`?

I have a class that has to set the `author` variable on HTTP GET. The HTTP POST will check if `author` exists, and then continue posting. I tried by having a global variable `author=None` and then setting `author` in the HTTP GET, but I think the object is destroyed when the HTTP POST request is made to the same controller.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can use sessions (cookies) to pass data between requests. See webapp2 sessions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the Datastore, or Memcache, are for. On the first request, save an `Author` entity to the Datastore or Memcache, and read it back when you need it for future requests.

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways.

1. Set cookie by first response and it will be passed to next request - unsafe even cookie is crypted but can be.
2. First GET will send author to second POST page - POST will send author (hidden field).
3. First GET will send author to POST url as param (same as above).
4. You will create session id and save in datastore and with author, GET will send session id cookie, PUT will send session id and you will read from datastore session id with author.
5. You can use memcache as datastore but it is dangerous (it can be flushed and data is not persistent in cache by design).
6. You can pass session id from GET to POST with use hidden field not cookie or url.

Consider the simples is GET and redirect to valid POST with variable in URL or in hidden field - other methods is more complex but it need chain of GET/POST.